# Не удается получить переменные класса в списке

Tags: java, классы, list, arraylist

Мне необходимо отсортировать список объектов класса, и вывести айди, название объектов

```
package com.para;

import java.lang.Comparable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class Program {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List fruitList=new ArrayList();
        Fruit apple=new Fruit(1, "Apple", "Sweet");
        Fruit orange=new Fruit(2, "Orange", "Sour");
        Fruit banana=new Fruit(4, "Banana", "Sweet");
        Fruit grape=new Fruit(3, "Grape", "Sweet and Sour");

        fruitList.add(apple);
        fruitList.add(orange);
        fruitList.add(banana);
        fruitList.add(grape);
        Collections.sort(fruitList);
        fruitList.forEach(fruit -> {
            System.out.println(fruit.getId() + " " + fruit.getName() + " " +
                    fruit.getTaste());
        });


    }
}
class Fruit implements Comparable{
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String taste;

    Fruit(int id, String name, String taste){
        this.id=id;
        this.name=name;
        this.taste=taste;
    }


    @Override
    public int compareTo(Object o) {
        Fruit f = (Fruit) o;
        return this.id - f.id ;
    }
}
```

Делал по примеру [Клик](https://www.journaldev.com/16094/java-collections-sort). Но у меня ошибка:

```
java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method getId()
java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method getName()
java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method getTaste()
```

Comment: Создайте методы-геттеры самостоятельно (`getId()`,  `getName()`, `getTaste()`) или воспользуйтесь  [Lombok](https://projectlombok.org/)

Comment: @Стас я новичок. Продемонстрируйте пожалуйста?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Указанная ошибка компиляции говорит об отсутствующих геттерах для полей класса `Fruit`:

```
java: cannot find symbol  symbol:   method getId()
java: cannot find symbol  symbol:   method getName()
java: cannot find symbol  symbol:   method getTaste()
```

Для доступа к свойствам/полям класса, объявленным как `private` используются методы геттеры (с префиксом `get`, для чтения), и сеттеры (с префиксом `set`, для чтения).

Их можно генерировать автоматически в любой приличной среде разработки типа Eclipse/IntelliJ IDEA и др., или же при помощи аннотаций [`@Getter/@Setter`](https://projectlombok.org/features/GetterSetter) или [`@Data`](https://projectlombok.org/features/Data) проекта Lombok, или, как бы это не было тяжело, написать их самостоятельно:

```java
// class Fruit
public int getId() { return id; }
public String getName() { return name; }
public String getTaste() { return taste; }
```

---

Однако, данная ошибка могла бы вовсе не возникнуть, если бы в классе `Fruit` был переопределён метод `toString`, отвечающий за строковое представление объекта (для его генерации также существует аннотация Lombok [`ToString`](https://projectlombok.org/features/ToString)).

```java
// class Fruit
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Fruit: id=" + id + "; name=" + name + "; taste=" + taste;
}
```

Тогда построчный вывод списка выглядел бы просто как:

```
 fruitList.forEach(System.out::println);
```

---

Кроме того, при реализации интерфейса `Comparable` следовало бы указать, что сравниваются именно фрукты, а не фрукты с любыми объектами.

```java
public class Fruit implements Comparable<Fruit> {

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Fruit f) {
        if (null == f) return 1; // null поместить в конец
        return Integer.compare(this.id, f.id);
    }
}
```

Тогда можно убрать излишнее приведение типов `Fruit f = (Fruit) o;`, которое может привести к `ClassCastException`.  Также при сравнении целых чисел лучше избегать вычитания, так как оно может привести к целочисленному переполнению, и использовать стандартный метод [`Integer::compare`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Integer.html#compare(int,int))